Sibling gender conditional probability puzzles — what information is “indexical”
Question: in conditional probability puzzles about sibling genders, what information can allow you to tell the siblings apart? Is there a good way to think about this kind of indexical information?
More details. Consider the following two classic probability puzzles:

A couple has two children. One of the children is a boy. What is the probability that both are boys?
A couple has two children. The older child is a boy. What is the probability that both are boys?

The standard answers are 1/3 and 1/2. In problem 1, no information is given, so we have three different options $(b,g), (g,b), (b,b)$, each equally likely. Hence 1/3 chance both siblings are boys. In problem 2, the additional information that older child is a boy allows us to “index” the two children. If we always list the older the older child first, our options are now $(b,b), (b,g)$, both equally likely. The point is that the information about the older child being a boy allows us to appropriately index the children.
My question is what kind of information allows us to index the children? Is there a theory of such information? Any good writing? I’m getting increasingly confused about what kind of information counts as “indexical”.
For example, consider the following variant, from Ross’s undergraduate probability book:

The king comes from a family of 2 children. What is the probability that the other child is his sister?

I would assume that “being the king” is indexical information. You could always list the child who is the king first. We have $(k,g), (k,b)$ as our two options, both equally likely. However, the answer in the book (as well as on Stack Exchange) is 2/3. It’s not that I don’t understand how they’re getting that answer — they simply aren’t treating “king” as indexical information. The thought process is that the king has to be boy, so the king comes from one of the following family structures: $(g,b), (b,g), (b,b)$. Further, I might respond that in this sample space, a family with two boys is twice as likely to have a child with a king, so we recover the “indexical” 1/2 answer.
Another example comes from naming the children (in some other puzzle book I have):

A woman has a son named Cain. What is the probability that she has two sons?

I would say that “is named Cain” is indexical, yielding an answer of 1/2, while the “book answer” is that “is named Cain” is not indexical, so the answer is 1/3.
Why is “older” considered indexical, while “is king” and “is named Cain” are not? One potential resolution to this is that we are not assuming kingships and names work as they do in the real world. For example, if we assume that in the case of two boys, both boys could be kings, or both boys could be named Cain, then clearly this extra information is not indexical.
What is going on?

"a family with two boys is twice as likely to have a child with a king" That probably does not quite say what you meant, as it is not like they can both become king independently. Regardless, it is a slightly confusing and poorly posed variant. It depends on what the monarchy succession rules are. There being a king rules out $(g,g)$. but may also rule out $(g,b)$ if that would also lead to there being a queen instead.

I disagree a little with their answer on Cain. In a family with two boys the parents have to pick two names from the name pool, so are slightly more likely to pick Cain than those families with only one boy. But that is only a very small effect of course.
